# SCSI disk not shown up during Rhel7 OS installation

Tags: rhel, system-installation, scsi, iscsi

In my system, I configured my SCSI disk and tried to install Rhel7 Beta2 OS on it. But for installation, I can't see the SCSI disk. If I'm trying to install other OS I can see the SCSI disk. I don't know what might be the problem.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Instead of raising bad flags, please [edit] your question and explain more clearly. Where is the SCSI disk not seen? Can you boot into a live system? If so, show us the output of `lsblk` and/or `sudo parted -l`.

Comment: That's why I asked if you can boot into a live system and *if so*, show us the output.

Answer (score 1):

Check RHEL7 release notes :
sg3_utils component, BZ#1186462
Due to the conversion of the iprutils package to use systemd instead of legacy init scripts, the sg driver is no longer loaded during system boot. Consequently, if the sg driver is not loaded, the /dev/sg* devices will not be present.

To work around this issue, manually issue modprobe sg or add it to an init script. Once the sg driver is loaded, the /dev/sg* devices will be present and the sg driver may be used to access SCSI devices.

found at:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/7.1_Release_Notes/Known-Issues-Installation.html

Comment: But i didn't installed OS as SCSI disk is not showing up. So, how can i install sg driver? And please do specify the path for sg driver. Thanks.

Comment: When you try to install an OS, you need to boot some media (DVD disk, PXE from network, USB pendrive etc). During this pre-install boot, certain drivers will be loaded - drivers which are necessary to handle devices on which the OS is installed. My guess is that the driver necessary for your scsi controller is not loaded and therefore you cannot see the disks. Of course there can be other reasons as well, but i installed numerous systems and usually in a similar situation a missing driver was the cause. As the Redhat "Known Issues Installation" article explains.